# While Upcasting I called method of base class(with virtual keyword) but after upcasting its calling override method from derived class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, downcast, upcasting

I am trying to understand Upcasting and DownCasting. In the code shown below, I upcast `Circle` object to `Shape` and after upcasting methods available are `Draw` and `Duplicate`, but when I executed `shape.Draw()` it is showing output from derived class - can anybody explain why?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Use Base class reference
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        //Up-casting
        Shape shape = circle;
        shape.Draw();           //output:- Drawing a Circle 
        shape.duplicate();      //output:- Duplicated!!    
    }
}

class Shape
{
    //Draw()available to base class Shape and all child classes
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Shape");
    }

    public void duplicate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicated!!");
    }
}

class Circle : Shape
{
   
    public override void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing a Circle ");
    }

    //Speciallized method available to only Circle class
    public void FillCircle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filling a Circle");
    }
}
```

Why is the output of `shape.Draw();` "Drawing a Circle" instead of "Drawing Shape" even though upcasting doesn't make access to any method from child class?

Comment: Because the circle remains a circle, event though you casted it. Casting is not converting, it remains the same object

Comment: Please read the documentation on [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override), and then you will understand. You can also refer to cly's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Draw` method declared as `virtual` in `Shape` which means the [runtime will look for overriding member on actual instance and execute it if found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual). It doesnt care what is the type of the reference you currently have to that instance.

Of course you wont see any `Circle` specific members while trying to call them using reference of type `Shape`.